# Grasping ODE by intuition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, intuition

Consider following differential equation

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = y^2(1+x^2)$$

Its solution is:

$$y(x) = \frac{-1}{x+\frac{1}{3}x^3+C}$$

As I read in one book, following must be satisfied:

$$\frac{dy(x)}{dx} = f(y(x))$$

And it is, plugging $y(x)$ to $y^2(1+x^2)$ will yield $y'(x)$, that is:

$$\frac{1+x^2}{(x+\frac{1}{3}x^3+C)^2}$$

Role of $\frac{dy(x)}{dx}$ is easy to grasp by intuition – $y(x)$ it's a function that matches slope "description" provided by $y^2(1+x^2)$, differentiating it will give the slope "description". But how to explain that $y(x)$ has to be substituted also on right side of $\frac{dy}{dx} = y^2(1+x^2)$?

Comment: It is a differential equation. So y needs to be replaced by its function, y' by its derivative, y'' by its double derivative etc. You ought to get an identity (in terms of x) on both sides of the = sign.

Comment: An equation is an equation.  "$y = \ldots$ is a solution of the equation" means that when you substitute $\ldots$ for $y$ wherever $y$ occurs, on both sides of the equation, you get a true statement.